# laravel process large amounts of data in function got database

Tags: php, database, laravel

So I have a function I am trying to run that basically goes through each account, gets all the sales for some time periods, adds them up and stores them in the db. The end goal is to run this function nightly so it doesnt have to be done when I present the data (since on a phone it would take forever to load a page). The issue is when i run this my computer over heats and the browser times out. Is there a better way to optimize?

Right now I run the function by going to a url (`localhost:300/account_sales`) since my route for that address calls the function (`Route::get('/account_sales','UserAccountsController@salesAddToDB');`)

```
public function salesAddToDB() {

    $accounts = Account::all();

    foreach ($accounts as $account) 
    {
        $current_month  = 0;
        $current_year   = 0;
        $last_month     = 0;
        $last_year      = 0;

        DB::table('sales')->select('quantity')
        ->where('account_vip_id', $account->vip_id)
        ->whereBetween('date', [
            Carbon::now()->startOfYear()->format('Y-m-d'), 
            Carbon::now()->endOfYear()->format('Y-m-d')
        ])->chunk(50, function($current_year_sales) {
            foreach ($current_year_sales as $sale) {
                $current_year += $sale->quantity;
            }
        });

        DB::table('sales')->select('quantity')
        ->where('account_vip_id', $account->vip_id)
        ->whereBetween('date', [
            Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d'), 
            Carbon::now()->endOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d')
        ])->chunk(50, function($current_month_sales) {
            foreach ($current_month_sales as $sale) {
                $current_month += $sale->quantity;
            }
        });

        DB::table('sales')->select('quantity')
        ->where('account_vip_id', $account->vip_id)
        ->whereBetween('date', [
            Carbon::now()->subYear()->startOfYear()->format('Y-m-d'), 
            Carbon::now()->subYear()->endOfYear()->format('Y-m-d')
        ])->chunk(50, function($last_year_sales) {
            foreach ($last_year_sales as $sale) {
                $last_year += $sale->quantity;
            }
        });

        DB::table('sales')->select('quantity')
        ->where('account_vip_id', $account->vip_id)
        ->whereBetween('date', [
            Carbon::now()->subMonth()->startOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d'), 
            Carbon::now()->subMonth()->endOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d')
        ])->chunk(50, function($last_month_sales) {
            foreach ($last_month_sales as $sale) {
                $last_month += $sale->quantity;
            }
        });

        DB::table('accounts')
        ->where('id', $account->id)
        ->update([
            'current_year'  => $current_year,
            'current_month' => $current_month,
            'last_month'    => $last_month,
            'last_year'     => $last_year
        ]);

        echo $current_year . '<br>';
        echo $current_month . '<br>';
        echo $last_month . '<br>';
        echo $last_year . '<br>';
    }
}
```

keep in mind the accounts has 40K records and sales has 60K total records

Comment: Have you tried just doing a `SUM()` query instead of adding in PHP? Also you should be able to call that controller action from the command line instead of the browser, which I think should make it a little faster.

Comment: @BrianGlaz no, I dont know sql very well so not sure how to write that and run it nightly. How would I do that in command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are doing about 100k+ queries here.  4 selects + 1 insert for each account which I think is the biggest issue.

This should take the place of all the select queries you have.

```
SELECT
    account_vip_id,
    SUM(IF(YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(CURDATE()), quantity, 0)) AS current_year,
    SUM(IF(YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(`date`) = MONTH(CURDATE() ), quantity, 0)) AS current_month,
    SUM(IF(YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(CURDATE()) - 1, quantity, 0)) AS last_year,
    SUM(IF(YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(`date`) = MONTH(CURDATE()) - 1, quantity, 0)) AS last_month
FROM sales
GROUP BY account_vip_id
```

Then you just loop through the results and update/insert your accounts table.

If you want to go further, you can modify this further to be an insert...select.  You'd need to put a unique key on the account_vip_id in your accounts table and add a `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` and that should turn your 100k+ queries into 1 query.

#### Edit

I've updated the query to remove need for looping through the results of the query, it should handle everything for you without needing to loop in PHP.  The only condition is that you need a unique key on the account so we can't create duplicates.

```
ALTER TABLE accounts ADD UNIQUE INDEX account (account_vip_id);
```

And the query itself...

```
INSERT INTO accounts
SELECT
    account_vip_id,
    SUM(IF(YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(CURDATE()), quantity, 0)) AS current_year,
    SUM(IF(YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(`date`) = MONTH(CURDATE() ), quantity, 0)) AS current_month,
    SUM(IF(YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(CURDATE()) - 1, quantity, 0)) AS last_year,
    SUM(IF(YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(`date`) = MONTH(CURDATE()) - 1, quantity, 0)) AS last_month
FROM sales
GROUP BY account_vip_id
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    current_year = VALUES(current_year),
    current_month = VALUES(current_month),
    last_year = VALUES(last_year),
    last_month = VALUES(last_month);
```

There is a potential bug here though, but was also pre-existing with what you were doing before.  If an account doesn't have any sales for the last 2 years, there is nothing to remove them from this table so it will seem as though they have sales data for last year, but they really will not.